# Consulta a Web Service con AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, webservice, cors

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a un `Web Service`, enviando dos parámetros de entrada, al momento de testear este código en `Firefox` con la herramienta de desarrollo me retorna los datos en formato son `JSON`, pero en mi código nunca ingresa al  `success` y no puedo manipular la información.

```
function enviar_as400 (){
    var dlunme =  '1110100000'; 
    var dlnuor = '20000851';                
    $.ajax({
         type: "GET", 
         url:  "https://xxxx/xxxxx/xxx/getMISDTLByDLNUOR", 
         data: "dlunme="+dlunme+"&dlnuor="+dlnuor,
         dataType:'json',
         success: function(datos){
             var resultado = JSON.stringify(datos);
             console.log(resultado);                
         }         
    });
}
```

Comment: El problema se debe a que el WS no soporta [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), entonces el navegador rechaza su contenido por cuestiones de seguridad. ¿Te interesa una respuesta usando `PHP`?

Comment: Claro, este mensaje me aparece: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at . (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).   Estoy trabajado con PHP y la consulta al web service la hago con ajax.  Agradeceria tu ayuda @Marcos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comentaba, el problema se debe a que el `WS` no soporta [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), esto provoca que:

> Por razones de seguridad, los exploradores restringen las solicitudes HTTP de origen cruzado iniciadas dentro de un script. Por ejemplo, XMLHttpRequest y la API Fetch siguen la política de mismo-origen. Ésto significa que una aplicación que utilice esas APIs XMLHttpRequest sólo puede hacer solicitudes HTTP a su propio dominio, a menos que se utilicen cabeceras CORS.

Una solución es crear tu "*propio `WS`*" con `PHP` y hacer la solicitud al "`WS` real", ya que las restricciones de `CORS` no afectan a las funciones del `PHP`.

#### Ejemplo:

En el archivo donde tienes tu `JS`, en lugar de hacer el `AJAX` al `WS`, debes hacerlo a tu archivo `PHP`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET", 
  url:  "[ruta]/ws.php", // AQUI apuntamos al PHP
  data: "dlunme="+dlunme+"&dlnuor="+dlnuor,
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(datos){
    console.log(datos);
  }         
});
```

y en el archivo `PHP` (`ws.php`), por ejemplo, puedes usar [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) para obtener los datos del `WS` real:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$params = '?' . http_build_query($_GET); // Obtenemos los datos enviados por GET
echo file_get_contents("https://xxx/xxx/xxx/getMISDTLByDLNUOR" . $params); // Los pasamos al WS
```

Comment: Excelente maestro. Funciona a la perfección. Agradecido por tu ayuda @Marcos

Answer (score 0):

Si del lado del servidor efectivamente te esta regresando un Json entonces utiliza :

```
    success: function(datos){
         var resultado = JSON.parse(datos);
         console.log(resultado);                
     }
```

La diferencia es que :

`JSON.parse()` toma un JSON string y lo transforma a un objeto JavaScript y `JSON.stringify()` toma un objeto JavaScript y lo transforma a un  JSON string.